# Convergence of the sequence:

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Convergence is defined as:
Given the sequence $\{a_n\}$, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|a_n - L| <\epsilon$ for n$\geq N$

Now, if I consider the sequence
$\{(-1)^{n+1}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ \
I take $\epsilon$=2 and $L$=0 then it satisfies the convergence definition for any $n$ because $\ |a_{n}-0|<2$ for all terms.
Where am I abusing this definition?

Comment: $\epsilon=2$ is not any $\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the definition "any $\varepsilon$" means "for all $\varepsilon$". In your example you only give one $\varepsilon$, but not prove for all $\varepsilon$-s. That is the reason the word "any" is not used much in literature, because it can be confusing. The phrases "for all" and "there exists" are used more as they are more clear.

Comment: Thank you does it mean all epsilon should satisfy the definition or else the sequence is divergent?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. If there exists an $\varepsilon$ for which the definition does not hold, the series does not converge.

Comment: Thank you so much, helped a lot